# Updating PHP and query for displaying catergories from database php mysqli

Tags: php, sql

Updating old code to php 7.3.5 and having trouble looping through a list of categories. Result should show each category available but only 1 is showing up. There are no errors.

Sample Data:

States are: South Carolina, Georgia, Illinois

Categories are: Commercial Community Development, Education, Infrastructure, Local Government, Public Buildings, Public Safety, Residential State, and Federal

Current output is:

```html
<div style="display:inline;"> <a href="/projects.php?state=SC&amp;category_id=21&amp;category_name=Residential&amp;disp_date=2019-03-18"><img src="/gov_images/Residential.jpg" alt="news category Residential" border="0"></a> </div>
```

This is the old code that worked great on PHP 5...

```html
<?php
  $sql = 'SELECT * FROM state_to_category WHERE state_id="' . $state . '"';
  // echo "<br>&nbsp;<br>Line #: " .  __LINE__ . " - Select SQL: *$sql*<br>\n";
  $sql_query = mysql_query($sql, $sql_link) or die("Could not select record: " . mysql_error() );
  // $row_ct = mysql_num_rows($sql_query);
  $state_id_list = "";
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_query))
   {
   $state_id_list[]  = $row['cat_id'];
   // echo "<br> state: " . $row['state_id'] . "  cat: " . $row['cat_id']; 
   }



  $sql = 'SELECT * 
    FROM news_category 
    WHERE type="base" 
    ORDER BY category';
 
  // echo "<br>&nbsp;<br>Line #: " .  __LINE__ . " - Select SQL: *$sql*<br>\n";
  $sql_query = mysql_query($sql, $sql_link) or die("Could not select record: " . mysql_error() );
  // $row_ct = mysql_num_rows($sql_query);
  $category_name = "";
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_query))
   {
   if ($category_id == $row['id'])
    {
    $category_name = $row['category'];
    }
   $state_found = "N";
   if (is_array($state_id_list))
    {
    foreach($state_id_list as $value)
     {
     if ($value == $row['id'])
      {
      $state_found = "Y";
      }
     }
    }
   if ($state_found == "Y")
    {
    ?>
    <div style="display:inline;">
    <a href="<? echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?state=<? echo $state;?>&category_id=<? echo $row['id'];?>&category_name=<? echo $row['category'];?>&disp_date=<? echo $disp_date;?>"><img src="<? echo $row['icon_small'];?>" alt="news category <? echo $row['category'];?>"  border="0" /></a>
    </div>
    <?php
    }
   }
?>
```

This is the same code that I'm working on updating to run on 7.3.5...

```html
<?php
  $sql = 'SELECT * FROM state_to_category WHERE state_id="' . $state . '"';
  
  $sql_query = mysqli_query($sql_link, $sql) or die("Could not select record: " . mysqli_error() );
  
  $state_id_list = "";
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_query))
   { 
   $state_id_list = array();
   $state_id_list[]  = $row['cat_id'];
   
   }



  $sql = 'SELECT * 
    FROM news_category 
    WHERE type="base" 
    ORDER BY category';
 
  $sql_query = mysqli_query($sql_link, $sql) or die("Could not select record: " . mysqli_error() );
  
  $category_name = "";
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_query))
   {
   if ($category_id == $row['id'])
    {
    $category_name = $row['category'];
    }
   $state_found = "N";
   if (is_array($state_id_list))
    {
    foreach($state_id_list as $value)
     {
     if ($value == $row['id'])
      {
      $state_found = "Y";
      }
     }
    }
   if ($state_found == "Y")
    {
    ?>
    <div style="display:inline;">
    <a href="<? echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?state=<? echo $state;?>&category_id=<? echo $row['id'];?>&category_name=<? echo $row['category'];?>&disp_date=<? echo $disp_date;?>"><img src="<? echo $row['icon_small'];?>" alt="news category <? echo $row['category'];?>"  border="0" /></a>
    </div>
    <?php
    }
   }
?>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Any sample data?

Comment: Update the question. Don't post in comments.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem updating at the same time the sql injection came up so i updated all my querys and loops and worked great

using PDO conector:

```
$mysql_pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DATABASE","user", "passwd");
 $query_categories = 'SELECT * 
                FROM news_category 
                WHERE type=:type 
                ORDER BY category';
    $Q_categories = $mysql_pdo->prepare($query_categories);
    $Q_categories->bindParam(':type',"base");
    $Q_categories->execute();
    while($row = $Q_categories->fetch())
    {
    if ($category_id == $row['id']) **<--maybe you lost $category_id on the update?**
                {
                $category_name = $row['category'];
                }
            $state_found = "N";
            if (is_array($state_id_list))
                {
                foreach($state_id_list as $value)
                    {
                    if ($value == $row['id'])
                        {
                        $state_found = "Y";
                        }
                    }
                }
            if ($state_found == "Y")
                {
                ?>
                <div style="display:inline;">
                <a href="<? echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?state=<? echo $state;?>&category_id=<? echo $row['id'];?>&category_name=<? echo $row['category'];?>&disp_date=<? echo $disp_date;?>"><img src="<? echo $row['icon_small'];?>" alt="news category <? echo $row['category'];?>"  border="0" /></a>
                </div>
                <?php
                }
    }
```

in this way you prepare your code for further updates and secure it against sql inyection mysqli_query is depecrated maybe thats why you are getting erratic behavior